# finding records that have a difference of more than 24 hrs using python

Tags: python

I run cron jobs on a daily basis and store there final status in a text file.

file data contains `start_time`, `end_time`, `cron job name`, `date`, `status`:

```
08/21/2017 18:31:47.000 EDT 08/21/2017 19:31:53.077 EDT create_dump 20170821 failed

08/22/2017 18:31:35.000 EDT 08/22/2017 19:31:51.000 EDT create_dump 20170822 failed
```

I would like to retrieve jobs that are in failed state for more than 24 hrs (when compared with system date).

comparison with end_time and value returned by datetime function

Comment: You need to show us the code you've tried.

Comment: use most use regex

Comment: which time should be compare with os time ? start_time ? or end-time?

Comment: compare end_time with datetime

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of os.stat to examine when what happened. Here is an example code..

```
def checking_the_dir_info():

x = os.scandir('/path/to/folder/')
print('Type of the object resulted by scandir is ', type(x))

for element in x:
    print('The element is on it own ', element, 'and the type of it ', type(element))

y = os.stat('./naber/asd.txt')
print('Last change date ', y.st_mtime)

from time import sleep

sleep(0.1)
z = open('./naber/asd.txt', 'a')
z.write(' Ne olacak bunun sonu :)')
sleep(0.1)

y = os.stat('./naber/asd.txt')
print('Birthtime of the file ', y.st_birthtime)
```

With the sleep function, you can observe that 'something' in the folder 'naber' has been changed and for all other different use cases, you can look to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)

Hope this helps!